# Accessing On-Chain Data In an Off-Chain Worker

Tags: storage, offchain-worker

I am looking to aggregate `On-Chain` data in an `Off-Chain Worker`, e.g. summing transaction fees included in blocks from the last 24 hrs. This is listed as one of the main use cases for [Off-Chain Workers](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/off-chain-features/).

However, I have not yet found a clean API for accessing this data. Is there a recommended way to read data from locally stored blocks? If not, are there best practices that should be followed? If possible, I would like to eliminate the need to make an external web request.

[Note]: As mentioned below, the [availability store](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/discussions/9701) is only on Polkadot and does not exist for general Substrate chains.

Comment: The availability store that Jeff mentions is actually a part of Polkadot: a blockchain built on Substrate. Thus there is no such thing as Availability Store in Substrate.

Comment: It's not very clear about your purpose. Do you want to make an index about transaction fees or you want to verify OCW ability ? Which is more important for you ?

Comment: We are looking to analyze transaction fee data over a period of n blocks in the runtime environment (OCW looks to be the most appropriate vehicle to do so). This information will not be stored and does not need to persist once calculated.

This would look something like:

calculate_transaction_fees(curr_block_number, n_blocks);
and would return the sum of the transaction fees over the specified range of blocks.

Comment: One way to work around the lack of history would be to have the OCW store the fee data indexed by block in offchain storage and then use that for the calculations.